# Migrate a SharePoint 2013 WSP (web part) to SharePoint 2019 (On-Prem)

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2019

I'm fairly new to SP 2019 (On-prem), but haven't had much luck finding information regarding moving a SP13 web part to SP 2019. It looks like I may have to recreate it using the SharePoint Framework. Does anyone have experience with migrating an existing SP 2013 webpart successfully to SP 2019 (on-prem) or is the Framework the only way to do that now?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you stick with classic-mode sites, you don't have to change a thing.  SharePoint already has [.NET Assembly redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) in place so that anything .NET assembly trying to reference the SP2013 or SP2016 .dll's will be directed to the SP2019 .dll's.

We just finished upgrading an Enterprise customer who has 30+ complex .wsp solution packages utilized across 2,000+ sites from SP2013 to SP2019.  The only solution packages we had to make modifications to were ones that dependencies on Third-party purchased products.  But we kept every migrated site in classic mode to achieve this.

Now, if you want to use the Modern UI on any of your SharePoint 2019 sites, depending on what your customization are, there is a high probability that they will not work.  If they are purely back-end Event Receiver and Timer Job type customizations, they may still work, but if they have any type of UI customizations, they will definitely break in the new Modern interface.  For front-end user-interface customizations, you would have to re-build your solution using the SharePoint Framework.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2019, still support to use WSP Web Part in classic page.

You can copy the web part solution into SharePoint 2019 and open with Visual Studio, change the SharePoint.dll reference to SharePoint 2019's version, rebuild and test if this web part have some exception, then deploy with Visual Studio directly.

Here are some points you will need to care:

[Consideration when upgrading WSP'S from One SharePoint version to another](https://www.techmikael.com/2016/04/considerations-when-upgrading-wsps-from.html)

For Modern Page experience, it's necessary to recreate SPFX Solution and achieve the same function.

[Build your first SharePoint client-side web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)